# consolidate duplicate records using stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database of persons that has some duplicates I need to clean up.   I have 
a stored proc that will merge 2 people together, but I don't know how to execute this from a loop somehow

Although there are a bunch of fields and tables involved, for simplicity's sake let's say
there's just one table Person which looks like this:

```
PersonID, FirstName, LastName, Organization, Email
1, Rick, Smith, Company A, rsmith@companya.com
2, Richard, Smith, Company A, rsmith@companya.com
3, Richie, Smith, Company A, rsmith@companya.com
4, Jonathan, Doe, Company X, jdoe@companya.com
5, John, Doe, Company X, jdoe@companyx.com
6, Michael, Johnson, Company X, mjohnson@companyx.com
```

What I would like to do is find all of the people who may be duplicated based on which ones have the same
fields equal.  For example, if I want to find all people who have the
same LastName + Email + Organization then I would merge the first 3 records into one and record 5 into 4.  I have
a stored proc to do that one by one:

```
exec mergePerson 2, 1
exec mergePerson 3, 1
exec mergePerson 5, 4
```

[edit]:  in this case the resulting output would be below  (this is simplified: the stored proc takes care of intelligently merging a dozen or so one-to-many tables in the background such as person-orders, person-contactnotes, etc).

```
1, Rick, Smith, Company A, rsmith@companya.com
4, Jonathan, Doe, Company X, jdoe@companya.com
6, Michael, Johnson, Company X, mjohnson@companyx.com
```

but how do I do this in bulk?  I think I need to do a while loop somehow, but not sure how to set it up.  I've seen some slick ways to delete multiple records on stackoverflow usine CTEs and partitions, but those are a bit over my head and I don't know if they can be applied here

It doesn't matter what order the merging is done in or which one is the source versus target.  That is,
this would work too:

```
exec mergePerson 2, 3
exec mergePerson 3, 1
exec mergePerson 4, 5
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: When you say merge, do you mean updating/inserting or just filtering out the duplicates?

Comment: Good question.  The merge stored proc deletes the duplicates after merging (there is a bunch of related information in other tables like orders that person has made, contact notes, etc).  In the first example, after the merge you would have just 3 records:  1, 4, 6.  This stored proc has already been written.

Comment: OK, let me update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by lastname, organization,email order by id) rn 
 from tbl)

delete from cte
where rn <> 1
```

The CTE basically numbers the records based on your criteria for detecting duplicates. Then the `delete` statement deletes the offending records from the table, except for the first occurrence of the record.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SAYKW24731)

Comment: Great, but I think it needs to execute the stored proc.  There is a ton of stuff that goes on in the procedure.  That stored proc determines how to best merge the records without losing information, pulls in the one-to-many tables (person-orders, person-contactNotes, etc) and merges those intelligently

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you share the code for the stored proc?

Comment: Oh man it's over 100 lines.  It's mostly updating the one-to-many tables.  For example, there is actually a table for all of the Email addresses associated with a Person, so the code has to merge them from the sourcePerson to the targetPerson without creating duplicates.  Your solution seems really close though.  In your example would there be a way to execute a command for all rows where rn<>1?  That would solve it I think

Comment: Well, you could get the rn <> 1 rows into a temp table or table variable, and iterate over that with a cursor. But that seems to be very inefficient.

Comment: Hmmm ... maybe it wouldn't be too bad though.  The table is < 10,000 rows and we'll probably only run it at night.  What do you think?

Comment: Well, I tend to avoid cursor based things and go for set based solutions where possible. But if this is a one-time thing, I'd probably say this should work, without knowing anything else about the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the strings you need to be the same, comparing them and selecting one of them in a method such as below.

```
SELECT Min(Person_id), First_name, (Last_name + " " + Organization + " " + " " + email) AS cc_string
FROm table1
GROUP BY  first_name,(Last_name + " " + Organization + " " + " " + email)
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting.  That would give me PersonIDs 1, 4, and 6, but I need the other PersonIDs to execute the merge stored proc.  How would I get those?

Comment: Good point- if you only ever have two duplicates, you could do the same as above but select the max. I would guess that from your description you have more than two duplicates per person.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at cursors?  A cursor will allow you execute a select query and then perform some procedure/steps on each row returned by the query.    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: Yes it looks like I will have to read up on cursors.  I'm having trouble getting my head around what the select statement will look like that I use with the cursor

Comment: Basically would do a cursor that will get all the rows shown above in your question and then for each row returned, you want to do another cursor that will search for all rows that are duplicates of the current one returned by the cursor. If at least one is returned, perform task, if no rows returned, go to next row in first cursor.